# Gin Rummy with Jokers

Tags: variants, gin-rummy

Is there any known variant of Gin-Rummy that **includes the Jokers**?

If yes then, what are the rules about jokers?

- How much deadwood a joker counts?
- Can be used only for Runs or also for Sets?

A [similar question on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1768030/question-about-jokers): (with no good answer)

> Aside from the fact that jokers are forbidden in Gin Rummy, does
>   anyone know what the next nearest, "quais-official" rules are for
>   including Jokers in Gin Rummy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various sites (e.g., [rummyculture](https://www.rummyculture.com/blog/rules-tips-tricks-for-the-joker-card-in-rummy/)) list rummy variants with jokers, but not Gin Rummy specifically. But the rules could be adapted directly. Suggested set of rules:

- Jokers are worth 30, as in most versions of Rummikub
- Discarded jokers cannot be picked up from the discard pile (optional)
- Jokers can be used in sets or runs, but not to make a 5-card set (the "missing" card must be one that exists).