# Name this variant of Rummy with mystery cards

Tags: identify-this-game, rummy

Any idea what it is variant of Rummy?

- 2 decks
- 10 cards dealt per player
- Mystery card can help to complete a set
- Meld all 10 of your cards.

Example would be 8c,9c,Jc and the mystery card being 10 of clubs to form the Run.

Comment: By 11 of club you mean Jack of club?

Answer (score 2):

### My guess is a variant of [Gin-Rummy with jokers](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/51161/gin-rummy-with-jokers)

The 10 cards starting hand is matching.  There are variants of Gin-Rummy where players can not knock (melding most of the cards), but must finish a round with Gin (melding all 10 cards)

Rummy is a large group of games (see: [pagat](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/), [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rummy)). If I understand you then the mystery card is a Joker.

Some details are missing to identify the exact Rummy game you are referring:

1. When a player laydown her cards, is it must be *all* her cards or she can have several cards that are not part of any meld?
2. Can players laydown Melds every turn and Add to melds of other (as in Contract-Rummy) or only at the round's end (Gin-Rummy)?